# Chalice AWS 504

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chalice

I have a chalice project (1.26.2) which is always exiting with a time out when deployed, chalice local works fine.

This is my project structure:

[image: Screenshot 2021-11-14 at 21 00 29]

This is the code in my app.py:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

import boto3
import firebase_admin
from chalice import Chalice, AuthResponse
from chalice.app import AuthRequest
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

from chalicelib import crud
from chalicelib import models
from chalicelib import schemas
from chalicelib.auth import full_user_from_context, user_from_context
from chalicelib.db import SessionLocal, engine

app = Chalice(app_name='server-aws')

BUCKET = 'meet-app'
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

cred = credentials.Certificate('chalicelib/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

DISTANCE_IN_METERS = 100

_DB = None


def get_db():
    global _DB
    if _DB is None:
        _DB = SessionLocal()
    return _DB


@app.lambda_function(name='test-function')
def create_user(event, context):
    return {'hello': 'world'}


@app.route('/health')
def health():
    return {'status': 'ok'} 


@app.authorizer()
def token_authorizer(auth_request: AuthRequest) -> AuthResponse:
    token = auth_request.token

    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(token)
        decoded = decoded_token

        allowed_routes = [
            '/auth',
            '/me',
        ]

        if 'permission_verified' in decoded and decoded['permission_verified'] is True:
            allowed_routes.append('/me/location')
            allowed_routes.append('/nearby')
            allowed_routes.append('/me/profile-image')

        print('routes', allowed_routes)

        return AuthResponse(routes=allowed_routes, principal_id=decoded['sub'], context=decoded)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error', e)
        return AuthResponse(routes=[], principal_id='non-user')


@app.route('/auth', methods=['GET'], authorizer=token_authorizer)
def authorize():
    u = user_from_context(app.current_request.context)

    user = crud.get_user(get_db(), u['uid'])

    if user is None:
        user = crud.create_user(get_db(), schemas.UserCreate(
            uid=u['uid'],
            phone=u['phone_number'],
            permission_verified=True # TODO: find verification method
        ))

    token = auth.create_custom_token(user.uid, {
        "permission_verified": user.permission_verified,
        "uid": user.uid,
        "phone": user.phone,
        "name": user.name,
        "linkedin": user.linkedin,
        "instagram": user.instagram,
    })

    return {
        'user': user.__json__(),
        'token': token.decode()
    }


@app.route('/me', methods=["PUT"], authorizer=token_authorizer)
def update_me():
    r = app.current_request
    u = full_user_from_context(r.context)

    data = r.json_body

    u = crud.update_user(get_db(), schemas.UserUpdate(
        uid=u.uid,
        name=data.get('name'),
        phone=data.get('phone'),
        instagram=data.get('instagram'),
        linkedin=data.get('linkedin'),
    ))

    if u is None:  # todo: code
        return {
            "error": "could not update"
        }

    return {
        "user": u.__json__()
    }


@app.route('/me/profile-image', methods=["PUT"], content_types=['application/octet-stream'],
           authorizer=token_authorizer)
def update_me():
    r = app.current_request
    u = full_user_from_context(r.context)

    data = r.raw_body

    file_name = u.uid

    tmp_file_name = '/tmp/' + file_name + '.jpg'
    with open(tmp_file_name, 'wb') as tmp_file:
        tmp_file.write(data)

    key = 'profile-images/' + file_name

    try:
        s3_client.upload_file(tmp_file_name, BUCKET, key, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
    except Exception as e:
        app.log.error(e)
        return {
            "error": str(e)
        }

    url = f'https://{BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}'

    u = crud.update_user(get_db(), schemas.UserUpdate(
        uid=u.uid,
        profile_image_url=url
    ))

    return {
        "url": url
    }


@app.route('/me/location', methods=["PUT"], authorizer=token_authorizer)
def update_me_location():
    r = app.current_request
    u = full_user_from_context(r.context)

    data = r.json_body

    lat = Decimal(str(data.get('latitude')))
    lng = Decimal(str(data.get('longitude')))

    loc = crud.update_user_location(get_db(), schemas.UserLocationUpdate(
        uid=u.uid,
        latitude=lat,
        longitude=lng,
        timestamp=datetime.now(),
        geo=f'POINT({lng} {lat})'
    ))

    if loc is None:
        loc = crud.create_user_location(get_db(), schemas.UserLocationCreate(
            uid=u.uid,
            latitude=lat,
            longitude=lng
        ))

    loc = schemas.UserLocationGet(
        uid=u.uid,
        user=schemas.UserGet(
            uid=u.uid,
            name=u.name,
            linkedin=u.linkedin,
            instagram=u.instagram,
            profile_image_url=u.profile_image_url
        ),
        latitude=loc.latitude,
        longitude=loc.longitude,
        timestamp=loc.timestamp.isoformat()
    )

    return {
        'loc': loc.json()
    }


@app.route('/nearby', methods=["GET"], authorizer=token_authorizer)
def nearby():
    r = app.current_request
    u = full_user_from_context(r.context)

    user_location = crud.get_user_location(get_db(), u.uid)

    if user_location is None:
        return {
            "error": "no user location"
        }  # todo: better errro

    nearby_users = crud.get_nearby_users(get_db(), u.uid, schemas.UserLocationGet(
        uid=user_location.user_id,
        latitude=user_location.latitude,
        longitude=user_location.longitude,
        user=u,
        timestamp=user_location.timestamp.isoformat()
    ), DISTANCE_IN_METERS)

    return {
        "nearby_distance_in_meters": DISTANCE_IN_METERS,
        "nearby_users": list(map(lambda x: schemas.UserLocationGet(
            uid=x.user_id,
            latitude=x.latitude,
            longitude=x.longitude,
            timestamp=x.timestamp.isoformat(),
            user=schemas.UserGet(
                uid=x.user.uid,
                name=x.user.name,
                instagram=x.user.instagram,
                linkedin=x.user.linkedin,
                profile_image_url=x.user.profile_image_url
            )
        ).dict(), nearby_users))
    }
```

This is the response when I invoke the test-function from the AWS console:

[image: Screenshot 2021-11-14 at 21 01 30]

This is what I get when I do chalice logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'crud'
Traceback (most recent call last):[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'crud'
2021-11-14 19:29:04.197000 88eb68 2021-11-14T19:29:04.197Z c143dcd4-e212-41f1-a786-7d86e4b58e59 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
chalice~=1.26.2
firebase-admin
boto3~=1.18.53
botocore
sqlalchemy
pydantic
# psycopg2
GeoAlchemy2
psycopg2-binary
```

I need to use psycopg2 so maybe that's the problem.

Every http request results in a 504 time out.

In local mode everything works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your chalicelib package folder's `__init__.py` (*it must be written like this*) has an extra underscore at the end of it. So python import system doesn't recognize such folder as a package, hence the error.